# Whenever I create a new branch it shows all files stored in master branch that it should be empty

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-code, branch

```
user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ git branch
* master

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 0 Jun 12 10:43 file1.py

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ git branch part1

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ git checkout part1
Switched to branch 'part1'

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (part1)
$ git branch
  master
* part1

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (part1)
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 0 Jun 12 10:43 file1.py
user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ git branch
* master

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 0 Jun 12 10:43 file1.py

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ git branch part1

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (master)
$ git checkout part1
Switched to branch 'part1'

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (part1)
$ git branch
  master
* part1

user@LAPTOP-LNQB4U6E MINGW64 ~/store (part1)
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 197121 0 Jun 12 10:43 file1.py
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems expected:

- either `file1.py` was not tracked (added/commited) to the master branch, and that private file would not disappear just because you are creating a branch
- or `file1.py` was part of the master branch, and creating a new branch from there would start with the master branch content.

Only creating an orphan branch ([`git switch --orphan`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch#Documentation/git-switch.txt---orphanltnew-branchgt)) would start with an empty content.

Note: if you are using Git 2.23 or more recent, use [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch), not the [confusing `git checkout` old command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this solution also gives me the same result....

Comment: @FahmidaOrsi What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.27.0.windows.1

Comment: @FahmidaOrsi in a git bash session, this should work.